# Comparing lines in two files to remove if they equal

Tags: python, file-comparison

I'm opening two files - one that contains the new file for comparison and one that contains the buzz words I need to remove from this file. I have this as a function so far:

```
def remove(file, buzz):
    #outer for loop cycles through the buzz file
    for line in buzz:
        #inner for loop cycles through the new file
        for line2 in file:
            if (line==line2):
                file.remove(line2)
            else:
                continue
```

where file is the new file that has been opened in `main()` and being passed to this, and `buzz` is the buzz file that is being opened and passed from `main()`.

The removal section is not working and the new file does not change.

Any suggestions?

Comment: For one thing, file objects don't have a `remove` method.

Comment: Are both files one word per line?

Answer (score 3):

First read the contents of each file and put them in lists:

```
a_list = open(file_a).read().splitlines()
b_list = open(file_b).read().splitlines()
```

Then remove the words in a_list that are in b_list:

```
a_list = [word for word in a_list if word not in b_list]
```

a_list now contains only the words that are not in b_list

Comment: This will work if every word is separated with a new-line character, otherwise will `a_list` contain lines of words that's not in `b_list`.

Comment: Yes, this assumes one word per line.

Answer (score 0):

Open and put file data into lists:

```
file_data = [line.strip() for line in open(file)]
buzz_data = [line.strip() for line in open(buzz)]
```

Then filter out the words:

```
new = [line for line in file_data if line not in buzz_data]
```

Finally write the new data to the file:

```
with open(file,"w") as f:
    for i in new:
        f.write(i+"\n")
f.close()
```